# Generating a character vector with a pattern

Tags: r

Simple problem, generate a vector of characters to like this:

```
"V1" "V2" "V3"
```

... up until "V50" .
Less memory consuming solution wins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really care about memory?  It'll be trivial in any case.  Try

```
sprintf("V%s", 1:50)
```